# Regex not properly matching when used with sed on CentOS

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to search for `<add key="CommunityWebSrvUrl"` and replace its value in a file like this:

Ex:

Before: `<add key="CommunityWebSrvUrl" value="https://example.com:12345" />`

After: `<add key="CommunityWebSrvUrl" value="https://somethingElse.com:54321" />`

I am currently using this shell script.
`rootDir="/replace/site/"
searchStr="(<add key=\"CommunityWebSrvUrl\")(.*)(\/>)$"
replaceStr="<add key=\"CommunityWebSrvUrl\" value=\"https:\/\/somethingElse.com:54321\/\" \/>"
sed -i "s|${searchStr}|${replaceStr}|g" "${rootDir}"WebApp/Web.config`

Shell script exists and its not replacing the string in the file, but I have tested the regex here  https://regex101.com/r/sW9xU4/27 and it matched the required string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matching regex does not work simply because you does not escape the parenthesis (if not escaped sed search for a "literal" parenthesis char).

```
searchStr="\(<add key=\"CommunityWebSrvUrl\"\)\(.*\)\(/>\)$"
```

Further, if you use pipe `|` as separator between sed substitution fields you can avoid to escape the slash `/` (the *default* separator).
Also if you use the single quote `'` you can avoid escaping the double quotes `"` inside the html.

So your script can be rewritten as this:

```
rootDir='/replace/site/'
searchStr='\(<add.*key="CommunityWebSrvUrl".*value=\).*"\s*/>'
replaceStr='"https://somethingElse.com:54321" />'
sed -i "s|${searchStr}|\1${replaceStr}|g" "${rootDir}"WebApp/Web.config
```

Comment: @kishorer747: i've updated the script to benefit from the match group (``\1`` in the substitution section, so you can avoid to repeat the first part of the string). Try it on centos, i've tested on a debian environment

Comment: hi, thanks. I fixed it after removing $ at the end in ```searchStr``` to your answer.

Comment: You are right it's not useful mix ``$`` in the match regex and use global ``g`` (global match tells sed to match multiple times in the same line, if we specify the entire content of the line it's a nonsense...)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rootDir="/replace/site/"
searchStr='<add key=\"CommunityWebSrvUrl\".*\/>'
replaceStr='<add key=\"CommunityWebSrvUrl\" value=\"https://somethingElse.com:54321/\" />'
sed -i "s|${searchStr}|${replaceStr}|g" "${rootDir}WebApp/Web.config"
```

- single quote for string *pattern* to avoid shell interpretation
- double quote around the full file name, not only path

you can also try to add double backslash in *pattern* due to double quote around the full sed action (ex: `add key=\"C` -> `add key=\\\"C`)

Comment: nope, still not replacing but not getting any errors either

Comment: tested here (opensuse) and works. Are you sure there is no space at end of the line to change in Web.config ?

Comment: sorry, copy paste was wrong, parenthesis are still there in my post. You don't need to group here because no reference to it in replace and no multiple occurence in pattern

Comment: this still doesn't work. but @GsusRecovery 's answer is exactly what I needed.